# Need to build a circuit resembling fluid flow through porous media

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I am trying to use electronics analogy to build a model that describes fluid flow in a porous media. For example I consider voltage, current and resistance to be equivalents of pressure, flow rate and permeability (inverse of resistivity), respectively. I need some help on how to choose more elements for my circuit to accurately model the fluid flow. Since I am not an electrical engineering student and I do not have a strong background in it, I would really appreciate the answers which start from the basics and move towards more complicated explanations.

Here is a list of things I need to know how to do:

1. I need to be able to control the time it takes for the current to travel from one point to another point. For example if points A and B are connected with a wire and A has a higher potential and I somehow increase its potential, theoretically there should be an immediate increase in the current flowing at point B. Is there an element I can put in between which controls the response time of point B to change in potential at point A?
2. I need to be able to model a variable permeability condition (i.e. variable resistance). I know if I use a resistor in my circuit it will have a CONSTANT resistance, so it will not help. Also, I want the changes in resistance to be proportional to the amount of current that has been flowing through that element. Like what happens when a capacitor is being charged, dQ/dt term is proportional to Q and it exponentially decreases to zero by time. But what if I don't want it to be decreasing exponentially? What other elements can I use to force the changes to be an arbitrary function of time/flow, for example a second degree polynomial? (if it's possible at all!) Also, is there a way to do the exact opposite i.e. the resistance decreases with time?
3. I am not sure if it is the same as part 1 or not, but how can I model the distance between two points in space? (The further the distance the longer it takes for it to respond to changes in another point of the circuit.)

Comment: You've given a good description but it "stands in isolation". More information will help us answer better. Why are you trying to do this? What will you achieve if you succeed? Why do you want to do this with an electronics analogy. A circuit could be built that does what you want. It becomes effectively a dedicated analog computer. This would be much easier as a 'program' for a digital computer so knowing why you want to do it this way helps.

Comment: I study petroleum engineering and as I said we are trying to model fluid flow through porous media. Honestly, at this point it is more like a research topic and if successful (maybe in many many years from now!) we can model more complicated reservoir and production methods using this analogy. And I don't really plan to build and actual physical circuit but at this point just pure modeling is the goal and if I could succeed, I will use a computer program to make the circuit and evaluate it. Also, I am not sure if I understood what you mean by the very last sentence.

Comment: Bob Pease used to describe a carbon-loaded paper that he could cut and shape to model current flow, and analyse voltage gradients along. Sounds as though it would be ideal for this application ... anyone remember what it was called?

Comment: There was a project in (I think) Europe which modeled a large river basin using discrete electronics the way you are talking about.  It was a long time back (like 1950-1960 or maybe earlier.)  I saw it in a TV show once.  I'll try to find a link to it.

Comment: Last sentence - a digital computer program would be an easy way to model such a system. Changing to an approximate analogy and modelling that sounds like a harder approach.

Comment: @BrianDrummond [Teledeltos paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teledeltos) is wot it is. One of the links has a UK source.

Answer (score 5):

It makes no sense to try to model this with electronics.  You'd need a whole lot of resistors and capacitors connected in a grid.  That would be time consuming to build, expensive, and failure prone.

Model your fluid flow on a computer.  There are various finite element modeling and solving techniques that have been applied to fluid flow for many years.  Use them.

Answer (score 2):

I found some links to previous analog hydrology models - not the one I had in mind, and I was surprised how much stuff was done in that direction.

These might help you see what is involved.  They all work with ground water, but the principles should be the same.

A look at some of the hardware should show you why everyone is suggesting you go digital.

I agree that you should do this job digitally, but reading up on the analog techniques might give you some insight into what your model must do.

Page 25 (as numbered by the author, 35 as displayed by the PDF reader) of the Houston paper show some of the needed formulas and relates the hydrology equations to the electrical ones.

Thanks to @George Herold for pointing them out

[European work](http://unesdoc.unesco.org/images/0001/000133/013392mo.pdf)

[USGS](http://pubs.usgs.gov/circ/1962/0468/report.pdf) - I had some trouble opening this one.  Save it and use Adobe Reader rather than viewing it in Firefox.

[USGS - Houston, Texas](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1974/0113/report.pdf)

Comment: Nice, See page 35 of the Houston paper for the relevant equations.  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

1. Unfortunately current travels at nearly the speed of light, therefore you have to "emulate" the propagation by using delaying circuits. Without going too fancy, you can use capacitors to introduce time constants in your circuit, but it will look more like a tank. But if you think digital, you can use buffers to make the transition sharp.
2. a. You can always use a variable resistor, also called potentiometer, to change the value at will.
   b. However, to have it decrease linearly (or with other function) over time you need some analog design: one possible solution could be an integrator with some feedback circuitry.
   c. The reciprocal of the capacitor (resistance decreasing over time) is the inductor.
3. You can use multiple delay stages, but with the same limitations of (1).

Answer (score 1):

You largely have it right.  There are a variety of conversion, but voltage maps to pressure, capacitance maps to a tank or a compliant chamber, inductance maps to inertia of the fluid, and resistance maps to resistance.

When you speak of a "porous medium", however, ganged elements may not be as enlightening to the questions you need to ask the model as a finite element modeling (FEM) approach.

For question 1, fluid travels, and current does not travel.  You would get current estimates, and then to see how long fluid takes takes to get from point A to point B, you would need to integrate across your current profile.

Answer (score 0):

First see JRE's answer for the relevant equations.

I'll be a voice in the wilderness and suggest that it's not crazy to make an analog model.
I've done this a few times when trying to model heat flow in an instrument.
(Temperature -> voltage, heat-> charge, heat capacity -> capacitance, thermal resistance-> R)  The advantage for me is that I can use some RC electronics/ circuit intuition to help understand what's going on and how I might improve things.  I've even gone so far as to load the circuit into LTspice, hit it with voltage steps (temperature changes) and added heaters (current sources.)  I find the act of building the model is really where my understanding takes place, and I'm not sure the same follows from FEA.  (I've rarely done FEA so I speak with little authority.)

But all this works for me because of electronics experience.  For @Ali Jamali, I'm not sure it will work as well... since he has no electronics background.
(my two cents)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds a lot like a model on an analog computer.

Start with the differential equations that describe the flow.

Dig out a GOOD textbook on analog computing.  They're still around, but they are NOT easy to find.

Do your homework.

You will wind up building a system of first-order differential equations that describe your model, scaling the equations for convenient analog computation, and then building a network of op amps that implement the scaled system of equations.  You'll scale in time, frequency, and range.  There is a lot of Black Art involved in all of this.

The good news is that op amps have come a long way since analog computers ruled the world of simulation, and it is now not all that hard to build an analog computer.

You very quickly will realize why the world moved to digital computers as soon as they got big enough and fast enough to replace analog computers for real applications.